# Save setInterval function() return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

```
  window.setInterval( function(){ FeedCache.getNext() }, 30000);
```

I need return value from `FeedCache.getNext()` after every 30 secs the interval calls that function. Is there a way I can save the return value something like,

```
  window.setInterval( function(){ currentFeed = FeedCache.getNext() }, 30000);
```

Than function returns an array of feed and based on one of the array element `displayImage` I need to change the `$location.path`.

I am working on cordova and ionic. The function `FeedCache.getNext()` is in `.factory` and i have `setInterval()` in controller.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i typically use objects laying around that both parts can see anyway. for example: FeedCache._timer=setTimeout()....  clearTimeout(FeedCache._timer);   of course, you need to make sure that you won't clobber timeouts if many timers will overlap, but that's rare, and usually, you have an instance of something laying around to use in that case.

Comment: I specifically need setInterval() function, because I need the getNext() function to repeat after a time interval. Is there any other solution?

Comment: oops, misread that. no problem, setInterval and clearInterval can be used in the exact same way. even so much that clearInterval(setTimeout('alert(123)')); doesn't fire the alert!

Answer (score 1):

You could save the return value in a global variable so your method could access it also any other methods could access it also.